# Leaflet marker not added to the map after click event on div element

Tags: leaflet, markers, typescript

I am trying to add a marker after performing a search, at a specific location given latitude and longitude.

For some reason, the browser runs the code but does not add the marker to the map.

```
//creating a search bar and adding events at searchBar.onAdd
const searchBar = new L.Control({
                position: 'topright'
            })

const mapResults: L.FeatureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup()

searchBar.onAdd = () => {

    const overlay: HTMLDivElement = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'search-bar')

    const searchGroup: HTMLDivElement = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'search-group', overlay)

    const img: HTMLImageElement = L.DomUtil.create('img', 'search-icon', searchGroup)

    const input: HTMLInputElement = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'search-field', searchGroup)

    const autocomplete: HTMLDivElement = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'autocomplete', overlay)
    
    let searchResults: NodeListOf<HTMLParagraphElement>

    const clearResults = () => {...} //remove searched items 

    this.map.on('click', clearResults);

     //make an Api call to populate the autocomplete with results(works nicely)
    input.addEventListener('input', (e: InputEvent) => {...})
    
    //add a click event listener to the autocomplete div element
    //and add the marker to the map
    autocomplete.addEventListener("click", (e: MouseEvent) => {
        const adressField: EventTarget | null = (<HTMLElement>e.target).closest('p')
        clearResults();

        //get lat and lng from clicked paragraph dataset 
        var positions = (<HTMLParagraphElement>adressField).dataset.position.split(',')
        var latlng = new L.LatLng(parseFloat(positions[0]), parseFloat(positions[1]))
        
        //create marker            
        const marker = new L.Marker(latlng);
        mapResults.addLayer(marker) //add marker to feature group
        this.map.addLayer(mapResults) //add feature group to map

        //set bounds(this works but no marker visible)
        this.map.fitBounds(mapResults.getBounds(), { maxZoom: 12 }) 

   })

   return overlay
}

searchBar.addTo(this.map)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the marker directly to the map instead of a leaflet Feature group. For some reason the Feature Group was not being added to the map.
I replaced the underlined lines with `marker.addTo(this.map)` and my marker showed on the map.
[image: code snippet]